# How to: publish Google apps script Sheets Add-on privately to my domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I am trying to publish a Google apps script Sheets Add-on.

In the editor the complete 'Directions' submenu is added to the Add-ons menu.

This is the submenu:

```
Directions >  
  Prepare sheet...   
  Generate step-by-step...
```

But when the add-on is published and a new spreadsheet is opened,
the 'Directions' submenu is added to the Add-ons menu,
but the 2 items are not added to the 'Directions' submenu.
and there is an error message:

> Error Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action.
> at onOpen(Code:10:36)

I have:

1. configured Google Workspace Marketplace SDK: visibility private
2. configured and published a Store Listing
3. followed the App URL to Install the Add-on to my domain

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Prepare sheet...', 'prepareSheet_')
    .addItem('Generate step-by-step...', 'generateStepByStep_')
    .addToUi();
}

/**
 * A function that adds headers and some initial data to the spreadsheet.
 */
function prepareSheet_() {}

/**
 * Creates a new sheet containing step-by-step directions between the two
 * addresses on the "Settings" sheet that the user selected.
 */
function generateStepByStep_() {}
```

Comment: You need to make a UI menu; try `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu` documented here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createAddonMenu()

Comment: I edited my question per your comment and re-published, but still have this menu:  Add-ons > Directions > Help

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now. Unfortunately, when publishing an add-on, the createAddonMenu function will only create a menu in the add-ons menu, rather than in each individual spreadsheet as a real google sheets menu, like File, Edit, etc. You could try using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu` documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createmenucaption but I can't make any promises that will work.

Comment: I edited my question with the steps to publish an add-on. `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu` is the correct answer. I had other issues related to not updating the `Sheets Add-on Script version` before publishing.

Comment: Great! Would love it if you could upvote my comment in that case :) thanks and glad I could help out.

Comment: Rolledback to revision 4 because questions should not be edited to replace the question by an answer, instead post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to use the method [addSubMenu(menu)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addsubmenumenu)

See also [Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

Sample:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Prepare sheet...')
              .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Generate step-by-step...')
                          .addItem("Help", 'generateHelp_')))
  .addToUi();
}
```

[image]

**Note:**

When you publish your Add-on, Google will add an additoinal default `Help` menu to the Add-on menu - in addition to your Help menu that is nested inside of `Generate step-by-step...`.

Comment: Hello @dak! I cannot see the comment you left before, but to answer your question of how having your menu separately intead of within the Add-on menu - unfortunately this is not possible when publishing an Add-on, your menu will always be embedded inside of `Add-ons`. I see, you significantly changed the content of your question, so my answer does not make sense anymore. For visibility purposes according to the Stackoverflow, next time it would make things less confusing if you would post a new question.